# Django - filter objects by number of related objects which meet a condition

Tags: python, sql, django

Given the following model:

```
class EmailVerification(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='email_verifications')
    token = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    expiry = models.DateTimeField()
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want to filter `User`s that have at least one verified email, so something like:

`User.objects.filter(num_verified_emails__gt=0)` where:
`num_verified_emails = EmailVerification.objects.filter(user=user, verified=True).count()`

Is there a way to accomplish this without using custom SQL?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overcomplicating the query a bit: all you want is Users who have at least one EmailVerification with verified=True. That can be done with a simple join:

```
 User.objects.filter(email_verifications__verified=True)
```

If you did need to filter on the actual number of verified emails, you could use annotations, but that's not necessary here.

Comment: Well that's embarrassing! I was under the impression that you could only do this for one-to-one relationships. Thanks a lot.